# HTML5 Canvas Color Picker Bug - When a new color is selected, color property is instantly updated on all objects in stroke history array

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, drawing, undo-redo

I'm working on a simple drawing app in Javascript using HTML5 Canvas, and encountered an odd bug after implementing a color picker.

For the undo/redo feature, every stroke is recorded as an object containing an array of point coordinates as well as a brushInfo object containing properties such as "color" and "width". When the canvas is undone or redone, it is cleared and then redrawn by looping through the points in every stroke and redrawing them using that information.

However, every time you select a new color, it immediately updates the "color" property on every single brushInfo object within every single stroke object in the history array. The result is that, when you hit ctrl+z, all strokes on the canvas are redrawn in the most recently selected color.

[I've recreated it in CodePen so you can try it out.](https://codepen.io/switchedonlotus/pen/QWGKjMe)

```js
// Set up canvas
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 400 * 2;
canvas.height = 400 * 2;
ctx.scale(2, 2);
ctx.fillStyle = "#000";

const colorPicker = document.getElementById("color-picker");

let isDrawing = false;
let currentPoint = {};
let lastPoint = {};

const strokePaths = [];
const undoneStrokes = [];

// Set default brush info
const currentBrushInfo = {
  style: "pencil",
  color: "#000000",
  width: 1,
};

// Information about the stroke currently being drawn
let currentStroke = {
  points: [],
  brushInfo: {
    style: null,
    color: null,
    width: null
  },
};

function distanceBetween(point1, point2) {
  return Math.sqrt(
    Math.pow(point2.x - point1.x, 2) + Math.pow(point2.y - point1.y, 2)
  );
};

function angleBetween(point1, point2) {
  return Math.atan2(point2.x - point1.x, point2.y - point1.y);
};

function getPointerPositionOnCanvas(pointerEvent) {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = pointerEvent.pageX - rect.left - window.pageXOffset;
  const y = pointerEvent.pageY - rect.top - window.pageYOffset;

  return {
    x,
    y
  };
};

function drawCircle(context, x, y, radius) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, false, Math.PI * 2);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
};

function onPointerDown(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  const {
    x,
    y
  } = getPointerPositionOnCanvas(e);

  lastPoint = {
    x,
    y
  };

  currentStroke.points = [];
  currentStroke.brushInfo = currentBrushInfo;

  drawCircle(ctx, x, y, currentBrushInfo.width);
  addPointToStroke(x, y);
};

function onPointerMove(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;

  const {
    x,
    y
  } = getPointerPositionOnCanvas(e);
  currentPoint = {
    x,
    y
  };

  let dist = distanceBetween(lastPoint, currentPoint);
  let angle = angleBetween(lastPoint, currentPoint);
  let spacing = 2;

  // Paints in between points to prevent gaps when drawing quickly
  for (let i = 0; i < dist; i += spacing) {
    let _x = lastPoint.x + Math.sin(angle) * i;
    let _y = lastPoint.y + Math.cos(angle) * i;

    drawCircle(ctx, _x, _y, currentBrushInfo.width);
    addPointToStroke(_x, _y);
  }

  lastPoint = currentPoint;
};

function onPointerUp() {
  isDrawing = false;
  currentPoint = {};
  strokePaths.push(currentStroke); // Records stroke in stroke history array
  undoneStrokes.length = 0;
  currentStroke = {};

  console.log(`Stroke history:`);
  console.log(strokePaths);
};

function setColor(e) {
  let color = e.target.value;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  currentBrushInfo.color = color;
}

function addPointToStroke(x, y) {
  const point = [x, y];
  currentStroke.points.push(point);
}

function clearCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

// Redraws the canvas using strokePaths array
function redrawCanvas() {
  if (strokePaths.length > 0) {
    strokePaths.forEach((stroke) => {
      let width = stroke.brushInfo.width;
      let color = stroke.brushInfo.color;

      ctx.fillStyle = color; // This *should* change the color for each stroke drawn

      // Loops through all the points in the stroke and redraws each one using the brush settings recorded in the stroke object
      stroke.points.forEach((point) => {
        let x = point[0];
        let y = point[1];
        drawCircle(ctx, x, y, width);
      });
    });
  }
}

// Removes most recent stroke from strokePaths, places into undoneStrokes array, then redraws canvas using the updated history
function undoStroke() {
  if (strokePaths.length > 0) {
    const undoneStroke = strokePaths.pop();
    undoneStrokes.push(undoneStroke);
    clearCanvas();
    redrawCanvas();
  }

  console.log(`Undone strokes:`);
  console.log(undoneStrokes);
}

function redoStroke() {
  if (undoneStrokes.length > 0) {
    const strokeToRedo = undoneStrokes.pop();
    strokePaths.push(strokeToRedo);
    clearCanvas();
    redrawCanvas();
  } else return;
}

// Event listeners

canvas.addEventListener("pointerdown", onPointerDown);
canvas.addEventListener("pointermove", onPointerMove);
canvas.addEventListener("pointerup", onPointerUp);

colorPicker.addEventListener("change", setColor)

window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.code == "KeyZ") {
    undoStroke();
  }
});

window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.code == "KeyY") {
    redoStroke();
  }
});
```

After each stroke, the stroke history array is logged to the console, so you can see the color properties change in real time.

I've been racking my brain but can't figure out what could be doing this, or how I can fix it.

Comment: `strokePaths[0].brushInfo === strokePaths[1].brushInfo`. You need to create a **new** brushInfo object for each path object.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks, but I'm not sure I understand. The brushInfo property on _currentStroke_ is updated with each pointerdown event on the canvas, at which point it's set to the value of currentBrushInfo at that moment:
`currentStroke.brushInfo = currentBrushInfo`

Then, when the mouse/pen is lifted, it adds currentStroke onto strokePaths: 
`strokePaths.push(currentStroke)`
Then currentStroke is cleared.

Is a unique brushInfo object not being generated any time the canvas is clicked? If not, what should I be doing differently?

Comment: Not it's always the one and only `currentBrushInfo` object you defined at the beginning. What you *should* do is up to opinions, but a few options: use a generator `function makeBrushInfo() { return { color: ...} }`, or always assign a copy `currentStroke.brushInfo = Object.assign({}, currentBrushInfo)` or make your stroke objects inherit from a class which will assign its own brushInfo at construction.

Comment: @Kaiido Ahhh, I see! Makes sense, thank you! ^^